# Abel-Plana formula for $\zeta(s)$, is this integral approximation correct?

Tags: numerical-methods, riemann-zeta, zeta-functions

I wrote a computer program to calculate values for $\zeta(s)$. I was scanning for something that would calculate complex values for $\zeta(s)$. I found the following approximation under the Integral section (7.5) of the Wikipedia page [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function). The Wikipedia page states that the Abel-Plana formula can approximate $\zeta(s)$ by

$\zeta(s) = \frac{2^{s-1}}{s-1}-2^s\!\int_0^{\infty}\!\!\!\frac{\sin(s\arctan t)}{(1+t^2)^\frac{s}{2}(\mathrm{e}^{\pi\,t}+1)}\,\mathrm{d}t \hspace{10mm}\forall\hspace{2mm}{s}\in\mathbb{C}\setminus\{1\}$

I did some testing and found that the approximation above seems incorrect for large values of s. $\zeta(2+3i)$ looks correct but $\zeta(100-7i)$ does not. Is there a way for me to verify that the equation above is correct?

Thanks for the answer from gammatester. I am only using double precision for the calculation of S2 - S1 which links to `Complex result = (S2.minus(S1)).divide(15.0);`. The Java program written is

```
/**************************************************************************
**
**    Abel-Plana Formula for the Zeta Function           
**
**************************************************************************
**    Axion004
**    08/16/2015
**
**    This program computes the value for Zeta(z) using a definite integral
**    approximation through the Abel-Plana formula. The Abel-Plana formula
**    can be shown to approximate the value for Zeta(s) through a definite
**    integral. The integral approximation is handled through the Composite 
**    Simpson's Rule known as Adaptive Quadrature.
**************************************************************************/

import java.util.*;
import java.math.*;

public class AbelMain extends Complex {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AbelMain();
    }

    // Main method
    public static void AbelMain() {
        double re = 0, im = 0;
        double start, stop, totalTime;
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Calculation of the Riemann Zeta " + 
                "Function in the form Zeta(s) = a + ib.");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.print("Enter the value of [a] inside the Riemann Zeta " + 
                "Function: ");
        try {
                re = scan.nextDouble();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
           System.out.println("Please enter a valid number for a.");
        }
        System.out.print("Enter the value of [b] inside the Riemann Zeta " + 
                "Function: ");
        try {
                im = scan.nextDouble();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
           System.out.println("Please enter a valid number for b.");
        }
        start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Complex z = new Complex(re, im);
        System.out.println("The value for Zeta(s) is " + AbelPlana(z));
        stop = System.currentTimeMillis();
        totalTime = (double) (stop-start) / 1000.0;
        System.out.println("Total time taken is " + totalTime + " seconds.");
    }

    /**
     * The definite integral for Zeta(z) in the Abel-Plana formula.
         * <br> Numerator = Sin(z * arctan(t))
         * <br> Denominator = (1 + t^2)^(z/2) * (e^(pi*t) + 1)
     * @param t - the value of t passed into the integrand.
         * @param z - The complex value of z = a + i*b
     * @return the value of the complex function.
    */   
    public static Complex f(double t, Complex z) {
        Complex num = (z.multiply(Math.atan(t))).sin();
        Complex D1 = new Complex(1 + t*t, 0).pow(z.divide(2.0));
        double D2 = Math.pow(Math.E, Math.PI * t) + 1.0;
        Complex den = D1.multiply(D2);
        return num.divide(den);
    }

    /**
     * Adaptive quadrature - See http://www.mathworks.com/moler/quad.pdf
     * @param a - the lower bound of integration.
         * @param b - the upper bound of integration.
         * @param z - The complex value of z = a + i*b
     * @return the approximate numerical value of the integral.
    */  
    public static Complex adaptiveQuad(double a, double b, Complex z) {
        BigDecimal EPSILON = new BigDecimal(1E-20);
        double step = b - a;
        double c = (a + b) / 2.0;
        double d = (a + c) / 2.0;
        double e = (b + c) / 2.0;

        Complex S1 = (f(a, z).add(f(c, z).multiply(4)).add(f(b, z))).
                multiply(step / 6.0);
        Complex S2 = (f(a, z).add(f(d, z).multiply(4)).add(f(c, z).multiply(2))
                .add(f(e, z).multiply(4)).add(f(b, z))).multiply(step / 12.0);
        Complex result = (S2.minus(S1)).divide(15.0);

        if(BigDecimal.valueOf(S2.minus(S1).mod()).compareTo(EPSILON) == -1
                || BigDecimal.valueOf(S2.minus(S1).mod()).compareTo(EPSILON) 
                    == 0) 
            return S2.add(result);
        else
            return adaptiveQuad(a, c, z).add(adaptiveQuad(c, b, z));
    }

    /**
     * The definite integral for Zeta(z) in the Abel-Plana formula.
         * <br> C1 = 2^(z-1) / (z-1)
         * <br> C2 = 2^(z)
         * @param z - The complex value of z = a + i*b
     * @return the value of Zeta(z) through C1, C2, and the 
         * quadrature approximation.
    */   
    public static Complex AbelPlana(Complex z) {
        Complex two = new Complex(2.0, 0.0);
        Complex C1 = two.pow(z.minus(1.0)).divide(z.minus(1.0));
        Complex C2 = two.pow(z);
        Complex mult = C2.multiply(adaptiveQuad(0, 10, z));
        if ( z.re < 0 && z.re % 2 == 0 && z.im == 0)
            return new Complex(0.0, 0.0);
        else
            return C1.minus(mult);
    }

    // Needed to reference the super class
    public AbelMain(double re, double im) {
        super(re, im);
    }
}
```

Complex variables program

```
/**************************************************************************
**
**    Complex Numbers        
**
**************************************************************************
**    Axion004
**    08/20/2015
**
**    This class is necessary as a helper class for the calculation of 
**    imaginary numbers. The calculation of Zeta(z) inside AbelMain is in
**    the form of z = a + i*b. 
**************************************************************************/

public class Complex extends Object{
    public double re;
    public double im;

    /**
        Constructor for the complex number z = a + i*b
        @param re Real part
        @param im Imaginary part
    */
    public Complex (double re, double im) {
        this.re = re;
        this.im = im;
    }

    /**
        Real part of the Complex number
        @return Re[z] where z = a + i*b.
    */
    public double real() {
        return re;
    }

    /**
        Imaginary part of the Complex number
        @return Im[z] where z = a + i*b.
    */
    public double imag() {
        return im;
    }

    /**
        Complex conjugate of the Complex number
        in which the conjugate of z is z-bar.
        @return z-bar where z = a + i*b and z-bar = a - i*b
    */
    public Complex conjugate() {
        return new Complex(re, -im);
    }

    /**
        Addition of two Complex numbers (z is unchanged). 
        <br>(a+i*b) + (c+i*d) = (a+c) + i*(b+d)
        @param t is the number to add.
        @return z+t where z = a+i*b and t = c+i*d
    */
    public Complex add(Complex t) {
        return new Complex(re + t.real(), im + t.imag());
    }

    /**
        Addition of Complex number and a double. 
        @param d is the number to add.
        @return z+d where z = a+i*b and d = double
    */
    public Complex add(double d){
        return new Complex(this.re + d, this.im);
    }

    /**
        Subtraction of two Complex numbers (z is unchanged). 
        <br>(a+i*b) - (c+i*d) = (a-c) + i*(b-d)
        @param t is the number to subtract.
        @return z-t where z = a+i*b and t = c+i*d
    */
    public Complex minus(Complex t) {
        return new Complex(re - t.real(), im - t.imag());
    }

    /**
        Subtraction of Complex number and a double. 
        @param d is the number to subtract.
        @return z-d where z = a+i*b and d = double
    */
    public Complex minus(double d){
        return new Complex(this.re - d, this.im);
    }

    /**
        Complex multiplication (z is unchanged).
        <br> (a+i*b) * (c+i*d) = (a*c)+ i(b*c) + i(a*d) - (b*d)
        @param t is the number to multiply by.
        @return z*t where z = a+i*b and t = c+i*d
    */
    public Complex multiply(Complex t) {
        return new Complex(re * t.real() - im * t.imag(), re * 
                t.imag() + im * t.real());
    }

    /**
        Complex multiplication by a double.
        @param d is the double to multiply by.
        @return z*d where z = a+i*b and d = double
    */
    public Complex multiply(double d){
        return new Complex(this.re * d,this.im * d);}

    /**
        Modulus of a Complex number or the distance from the origin in
        * the polar coordinate plane.
        @return |z| where z = a + i*b.
    */
    public double mod() {
        if ( re != 0.0 || im != 0.0)
            return Math.sqrt(re*re + im*im);
        else
            return 0.0;
    }

    /**
     * Modulus of a Complex number squared
     * @param z = a + i*b
     * @return |z|^2 where z = a + i*b
    */
    public double abs(Complex z) {
        return Math.sqrt(Math.pow(re*re, 2) + Math.pow(im*im, 2));
    }


    /**
        Division of Complex numbers (doesn't change this Complex number).
        <br>(a+i*b) / (c+i*d) = (a+i*b)*(c-i*d) / (c+i*d)*(c-i*d) =
        * (a*c+b*d) + i*(b*c-a*d) / (c^2-d^2)
        @param t is the number to divide by
        @return new Complex number z/t where z = a+i*b  
    */
    public Complex divide (Complex t) {
        double denom = Math.pow(t.mod(), 2); // Square the modulus
        return new Complex((re * t.real() + im * t.imag()) / denom, 
                (im * t.real() - re * t.imag()) / denom);
    }

   /**
        Division of Complex number by a double.
        @param d is the double to divide
        @return new Complex number z/d where z = a+i*b  
    */
    public Complex divide(double d){
        return new Complex(this.re / d, this.im / d);
    }

    /**
        Exponential of a complex number (z is unchanged).
        <br> e^(a+i*b) = e^a * e^(i*b) = e^a * (cos(b) + i*sin(b))
        @return exp(z) where z = a+i*b
    */
    public Complex exp () {
        return new Complex(Math.exp(re) * Math.cos(im), Math.exp(re) *
                Math.sin(im));
    }


     /**
        The Argument of a Complex number or the angle in radians 
        with respect to polar coordinates.
        <br> Tan(theta) = b / a, theta = Arctan(b / a)
        <br> a is the real part on the horizontal axis
        <br> b is the imaginary part of the vertical axis
        @return arg(z) where z = a+i*b.
    */
    public double arg() {
        return Math.atan2(im, re);
    }


    /**
        The log or principal branch of a Complex number (z is unchanged).
        <br> Log(a+i*b) = ln|a+i*b| + i*Arg(z) = ln(sqrt(a^2+b^2)) 
        * + i*Arg(z) = ln (mod(z)) + i*Arctan(b/a)
        @return log(z) where z = a+i*b
    */
    public Complex log() {
        return new Complex(Math.log(this.mod()), this.arg());
    }

    /**
        The square root of a Complex number (z is unchanged).
        Returns the principal branch of the square root.
        <br> z = e^(i*theta) = r*cos(theta) + i*r*sin(theta) 
        <br> r = sqrt(a^2+b^2)
        <br> cos(theta) = a / r, sin(theta) = b / r
        <br> By De Moivre's Theorem, sqrt(z) = sqrt(a+i*b) = 
        * e^(i*theta / 2) = r(cos(theta/2) + i*sin(theta/2))
        @return sqrt(z) where z = a+i*b
    */
    public Complex sqrt() {
        double r = this.mod();
        double halfTheta = this.arg() / 2;
        return new Complex(Math.sqrt(r) * Math.cos(halfTheta), Math.sqrt(r) * 
                Math.sin(halfTheta));
    }


    /**
        The real cosh function for Complex numbers.
        <br> cosh(theta) = (e^(theta) + e^(-theta)) / 2
        @return cosh(theta)
    */
    private double cosh(double theta) {
        return (Math.exp(theta) + Math.exp(-theta)) / 2;
    }

    /**
        The real sinh function for Complex numbers.
        <br> sinh(theta) = (e^(theta) - e^(-theta)) / 2
        @return sinh(theta)
    */
    private double sinh(double theta) {
        return (Math.exp(theta) - Math.exp(-theta)) / 2;
    }

     /**
        The sin function for the Complex number (z is unchanged).
        <br> sin(a+i*b) = cosh(b)*sin(a) + i*(sinh(b)*cos(a))
        @return sin(z) where z = a+i*b
    */
    public Complex sin() {
        return new Complex(cosh(im) * Math.sin(re), sinh(im)* 
                Math.cos(re));
    }

    /**
        The cos function for the Complex number (z is unchanged).
        <br> cos(a +i*b) = cosh(b)*cos(a) + i*(-sinh(b)*sin(a))
        @return cos(z) where z = a+i*b
    */
    public Complex cos() {
        return new Complex(cosh(im) * Math.cos(re), -sinh(im) * 
                Math.sin(re));
    }

    /**
        The hyperbolic sin of the Complex number (z is unchanged).
        <br> sinh(a+i*b) = sinh(a)*cos(b) + i*(cosh(a)*sin(b))
        @return sinh(z) where z = a+i*b
    */
    public Complex sinh() {
        return new Complex(sinh(re) * Math.cos(im), cosh(re) * 
                Math.sin(im));
    }

    /**
        The hyperbolic cosine of the Complex number (z is unchanged).
        <br> cosh(a+i*b) = cosh(a)*cos(b) + i*(sinh(a)*sin(b))
        @return cosh(z) where z = a+i*b
    */
    public Complex cosh() {
        return new Complex(cosh(re) *Math.cos(im), sinh(re) * 
                Math.sin(im));
    }

    /**
        The tan of the Complex number (z is unchanged).
        <br> tan (a+i*b) = sin(a+i*b) / cos(a+i*b)
        @return tan(z) where z = a+i*b
    */
    public Complex tan() {
        return (this.sin()).divide(this.cos());
    }

    /**
        The arctan of the Complex number (z is unchanged).
        <br> tan^(-1)(a+i*b) = 1/2 i*(log(1-i*(a+b*i))-log(1+i*(a+b*i))) =
        <br> -1/2 i*(log(i*a - b+1)-log(-i*a + b+1))
        @return arctan(z) where z = a+i*b
    */
    public Complex atan(){
        Complex ima = new Complex(0.0,-1.0);    //multiply by negative i
        Complex num = new Complex(this.re,this.im-1.0);
        Complex den = new Complex(-this.re,-this.im-1.0);
        Complex two = new Complex(2.0, 0.0);    // divide by 2
        return ima.multiply(num.divide(den).log()).divide(two);
    }

    /**
     * The Math.pow equivalent of two Complex numbers.
     * @param z - the complex base in the form z = a + i*b
     * @return z^y where z = a + i*b and y = c + i*d
    */
    public Complex pow(Complex z){
        Complex a = z.multiply(this.log());
        return a.exp();
    }

    /**
     * The Math.pow equivalent of a Complex number to the power
         * of a double.
     * @param d - the double to be taken as the power.
     * @return z^d where z = a + i*b and d = double
    */
     public Complex pow(double d){
         Complex a=(this.log()).multiply(d);
         return a.exp();
     }

    /**
        Override the .toString() method to generate complex numbers, the
        * string representation is now a literal Complex number.
        @return a+i*b, a-i*b, a, or i*b as desired.
    */
    public String toString() {
        if (re != 0.0 && im  > 0.0) {
            return re + " + " + im +"*i";
        }
        if (re !=0.0 && im < 0.0) {
            return re + " - "+ (-im) + "*i";
        }
        if (im == 0.0) {
            return String.valueOf(re);
        }
        if (re == 0.0) {
            return im + "*i";
        }
        return re + " + i*" + im;       
    }   
}
```

Comment: DLMF list the same formula with slighty other variable names in 
http://dlmf.nist.gov/25.5.E12

Comment: What do you mean with incorrect? What programming language do you use? IMO the value for $\zeta(100-7i) = 1  +0.1097998919157576\times 10^{-30} -0.811821244251574\times 10^{-30}i$ cannot be computed by numerical evaluation of the integral using e.g. double-precision floating point without kind of pre-processing. For $z=100-7i$ you subtract two terms of order $2^{100}$ to get a value of order $1$, so you must at least compute with about 150 bit precision

Comment: I think I see my mistake (at work right now so will need to test tonight). I am computing the values of S1 - S2 with double precision. This is definitely incorrect and would need to be through BigDecimal. I will also try the other representations presented by the hyperlink. Thank You gammatester.

Comment: For a good ref on integral representation of Riemann zeta function, you may want to take a look at a paper by Michael S.Milgram, 2012, titled "Integral and Series Representations of Riemann' s Zeta function, Dirichelet' s Eta Function and a Medley of Related Results."

Comment: @gammatester: I think you lost a leading 7 digit in the imaginary part of $\zeta(100-7i)$. Using mpmath I get -7.8118212442515740797416...e-31

Comment: @PM 2Ring: Yes you are right, I noticed this some time after the editing period expired.

Comment: Abel-Plana is not terribly efficient. For large arguments, you can just directly use the Dirichlet series.